# Can you create custom VS Code snippets variables?

Tags: visual-studio-code, variables, transformation, code-snippets

According to the VS Code documentation: [snippets variables](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_variables) , one can use certain variables to properly customize the snippets. They also work with [Transformations](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_variable-transforms), which make the custom snippets even more powerful.

I wonder if there is any way to create custom variables that can be used in the snippets' generation?

The documentation defined variables work just fine in the snippets generation.